# PyDirectInput Mouse Movement Is Very Sensitive

Tags: automation, minecraft, pyautogui

I have been playing around with pyautogui before switching to pydirectinput in order to automate things in Minecraft. I'm making a mining bot and I'm running into some issues involving automated mouse movement in the game. I'm using the moveRel() function, although I have used move() and moveTo(), they produced the same result as moveRel(), to move the player's head up and down. However, even when I put the Offsets to a really low amount like 1, the player's head rotates in a full range of motion. To help you visualize this, in Minecraft, picture your character staring off into the horizon. Now imagine what would happen if you suddenly jerked the mouse back. The player would face down right? Well, every time I try moving the mouse a little bit using pydirectinput, the player always ends up facing down. What is causing the player to look down as if its camera were anchored when I use the mouse moving function in pydirectinput?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved My Problem. It turns out that I need to turn on Raw Input so that the mouse wouldn't accelerate so much. Raw Input uses the raw mouse movement from your computer meaning that it does not accelerate or deaccelerate the mouse input to match the game sensitivity. I think that's how it works. By the way, raw input is in the mouse control settings in Minecraft. Anyway, because of the acceleration of my mouse input, the simulated mouse movement from my pydirectinput script was too sensitive for the game, so that's why the player always looked downwards no matter what numbers I put into the moveRel() function.